# SVG order of transforms

Tags: svg, transform

Does the order of transform functions matter in SVG `transform`? For instance if i want to `scale` a shape but preserving the original coordinates specified in it's `translate`, would it help to first `translate` and then `scale`:

```xml
transform="translate(100 100) scale(0.5)"
```

will change the size but not the `100 100` placement, wheras

```xml
transform="scale(0.5) translate(100 100)"
```

does change both the size and the placement?

Comment: What happens when you try these two approaches? To be honest, I think trying them out would answer your question.

Answer (score 3):

SVG transforms are applied in reverse order (e.g right-to-left) as detailed in the W3C spec: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#svg-transform-functions

> "the individual SVG transform functions must get post-multiplied"